# SQL count how many times a value appears across multiple columns?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Below is an example of a table in our CRM, its not the way I'd have chosen to store this data but thats by the by,  What would be the 'nice' way to count how many times each option was selected by each team?

asking here before i go headlong into a convoluted case statement :)

```
+----------+--------+---------+---------+---------+
| PersonID |  Team  | Option1 | Option2 | Option3 |
+----------+--------+---------+---------+---------+
|        1 | Blue   | A       | B       | C       |
|        2 | Blue   | B       | C       | D       |
|        3 | Blue   | D       | A       | E       |
|        4 | Red    | A       | B       | D       |
|        5 | Red    | B       | A       | C       |
|        6 | Yellow | A       | B       | C       |
|        7 | Yellow | A       | C       | D       |
+----------+--------+---------+---------+---------+
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: what SQL have you tried?

Comment: Thanks for the formatting... i'm new here and didnt realise posting that way would show the whole code rather than just a table :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can unpivot your 3 option columns into a single column using `CROSS APPLY` and a table value constructor and then perform your count:

```
SELECT  t.Team, upvt.[Option], COUNT(*) AS Occurances
FROM    dbo.T
CROSS APPLY (VALUES (t.Option1), (t.Option2), (t.Option3)) AS upvt ([Option])
GROUP BY t.Team, upvt.[Option]
ORDER BY t.Team, upvt.[Option];
```

So this would give:

```
Team       Option   Occurances
-------------------------------
Blue        A           2
Blue        B           2
Blue        C           2
Blue        D           2
Blue        E           1
Red         A           2
Red         B           2
Red         C           1
Red         D           1
Yellow      A           2
Yellow      B           1
Yellow      C           2
Yellow      D           1
```

Comment: Seems perfect, will try that thanks.. looks like alot of options contain NULL so will just have to account there

Answer (score 0):

You can use UNION ALL to move the values into single column and then, do aggregation:

```
select 
    team, option, count(*) cnt
from(
    select team, option1 option from t union all
    select team, option2 from t union all
    select team, option3 from t 
)t group by team, option;
```